# socket in blocking mode

Tags: sockets, network-programming, timeout, blocking, nonblocking

Do you think using **select()** with blocking socket is a good idea or better use timeout **SO_SNDTIMEO/SO_RCVTIMEO**

(I'm under Linux, socket is sets on SOCK_STREAM)

The advantage with the first solution is that it could work with any type of sockets (blocking and/or non-blocking state)

Comment: Stef - could you elaborate on the details a bit more?  Linux or Windows?  SOCK_STREAM or SOCK_DGRAM?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to followup `select()` with `read()`/`write()`/`send()`/etc.. when it returns ready conditions, you certainly have to be really careful if your file descriptors are in blocking mode. For reads, you have to make really sure you only read once after you get a read-ready indication because the second one might block. For writes it's probably worse: I imagine there could be obscure conditions under which the socket is reported ready by `select()` but something happens and it's no longer ready by the time you `write()` to it. Even if this last supposition is too pessimistic, I would consider this solution to be unmaintainable and bad practice.

Considering it's not difficult to switch a file descriptor dynamically from blocking to nonblocking and back using `fcntl()`, you are you so concerned about being compatible with blocking sockets? Just change them to nonblocking.